# Problems with Ampps

Tags: php, installation, fatal-error, dispatcher

I have installed Impresspages on my local Ampps server. When I proceed to open it, I get error message:

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Ip\ctype_digit() in /Applications/AMPPS/www/impresspage/Ip/Dispatcher.php on line 197
```

Here is line 197 from Dispatcher.php:

```
if (ctype_digit($priority)) {
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 16):

Enable PHP Extension *ctype* from **AMPPS Application -> PHP Tab -> PHP Extension**.

Comment: You will need to restart apache after enabling that extension.

Comment: not able to find this extension. Can you explain it in detail please?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the AMMPS Application
2. Stop Apache
3. Goto PHP tab
4. Open PHP Extension window by clicking
5. Tick `ctype.so` and apply
6. Start Apache
7. You are done!